# Particular one-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a Rails 3.1 app with a `User` model and a `House` model (this is like a group). I've set up a many-to-many relation with join model `Membership` between those two and there are methods to manages roles of a user in some house in the join model.

But my problem is that a User has only one house and not many. So I always have to do user.houses.first to get his house (I've set up a helper house which does that) but the design is not good so I've tried to put `has_one :membership` and `has_one :house, :through => :membership` instead of `has_many :memberships` and `has_many :houses, :through => :memberships`. But I got an error each time I try to access house from `User`.

How is it possible to set up this one-to-many relation with a join table like I was trying to do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Im confused, in your DB model, can User have only one house or many houses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the one to many relation then association should be.

*House*

**has_many** :memberships

**has_many** :users, :through => :memberships

*User*

**has_one** :membership

**has_one** :house, :through => :membership

Comment: I got an error message. But now it works after having restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way doing this with relations, however you could leave it as the plural and then just define house in users:

```
class User 
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :houses, :through => :memberships

  def house
    houses.first
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried to implement `house=` too with `delete_all` and `<<` but that's a little tricky, isn't it ?

Comment: Shouldn't be too dificult can you not just do houses = [new_house]

Comment: @Skydreamer it is tricky, but your schema is not a proper one for a one to many relationship.