# Rails one to many through a relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Company that has many Users through a join table company_user. Each user should work for only one Company. This is a 1 to many relationship.

I have looked around for this and found the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080017/883102

But I get the error

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
>   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass

When I try to create a Company. How can I solve this?

My models are

Company

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, :through => :employments
end
```

Users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Employment

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The migration for my join table is

```
create_table :employment do |t|
    t.belongs_to :company
    t.belongs_to :user
    t.timestamps
end
```

My schema.rb

```
create_table "company", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "rating"
  t.integer  "phone"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "address"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "employment", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
  t.string   "role"
end
```

Comment: You created the table `company_user` when I believe you needed `company_users` (plural)

Comment: hi I tried this but no joy unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post scheme.rb so I can see what you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318236/883102

The problem was that my table names were in the singular form, I changed these in the migration and then re-created the database. It all seems to be working fine now.

My User class ended up as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :employment
  has_one :company, :through => :employment
end
```

This was to allow bi-directional associations